# How to installation spark standalone mode in ubuntu

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install spark standalone but show error.
How i can solve this problem.

- Java version :- 1.8.0_131
- Spark:- 2.2.0
- Hadoop: 2.7.4
- bashrc file setting
- Hadoop file location in local System: `/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.4`
- Spark file location: `/opt/spark/spark`

File:

```
-----------------------------
#JAVA HOME directory setup
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

#HBASE HOME setup
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-1.3.1
export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_HOME/bin

#HADOOP Setup
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.4
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME  
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/hadoop2_data/hdfs/pid

#spark setup
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
#scala 
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.11.11
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots/images where [text will do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)! Looks like a $CLASSPATH error to me. I think we need more detail as to what, exactly, you have done so far! You can edit your own question - don't forget the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)!

Comment: Ok I will post more detail

Comment: Remove the image and paste in the text using the formatting for a code block! Provide the output of `env | sort` (again, formatted text!).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted in either [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) (Server Fault is a question and answer site for system and network administrators.) or in [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com) (Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `pip pyspark`, as it's super easy

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install pyspark
$ pyspark
```

You can modify Spark configuration by adding files to `venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/pyspark/conf/`